# how can one increase size of plotted area wordclouds in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tag-cloud, word-cloud

trying to replicate the example here;

http://onertipaday.blogspot.com/2011/07/word-cloud-in-r.html

Need help figuring out how to increase the plotted area of the word cloud. Changing the height and width parmeters in  png("wordcloud_packages.png", width=1280,height=800) only changes the height and width of the canvas..but the plotted area remains small.

```
require(XML)
require(tm)
require(wordcloud)
require(RColorBrewer)
u = "http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html"
t = readHTMLTable(u)[[1]]
ap.corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(as.character(t[,3]))))
ap.corpus <- tm_map(ap.corpus, removePunctuation)
ap.corpus <- tm_map(ap.corpus, tolower)
ap.corpus <- tm_map(ap.corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))
ap.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(ap.corpus)
ap.m <- as.matrix(ap.tdm)
ap.v <- sort(rowSums(ap.m),decreasing=TRUE)
ap.d <- data.frame(word = names(ap.v),freq=ap.v)
table(ap.d$freq)
pal2 <- brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")
png("wordcloud_packages.png", width=1280,height=800)
wordcloud(ap.d$word,ap.d$freq, scale=c(8,.2),min.freq=3,
max.words=Inf, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=.15, colors=pal2)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using the `res` parameter, instead:

```
...
png("wordcloud_packages.png", width=12,height=8, units='in', res=300)
...
```

[image]

Comment: this is helpful..thanks.  I will update this question if I find a better answer.

Comment: thanks for the tip. just wondering if you've come across an issue where the text size doesn't scale with the word frequency? running the examples on my system, the words are all the same size. could be an issue with system fonts. tia.

Comment: nvm, indeed, it was an issue with system fonts! in any case, here's a good how-to on installing additional fonts: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html

Answer (score 2):

If you include `par(mar = rep(0, 4))` as a separate line immediately after the call to `png` you'll remove the margins, and the wordcloud will use all the available space. With this, and possibly tweaking the `res` parameter as suggested in the previous answer, you should get what you wanted.